# Find the slope at $t=16$ for $s(t) = $arctan$(\sqrt{t})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> A particle moves along the x axis so that its position at any time when t is greater than or equals zero is $s(t) = $arctan$(\sqrt{t})$. Find the velocity of the particle at $t=16$.

The point of this question isn't to find the velocity, but to solve for the derivative and then find the slope of the line at a certain point. The velocity is the slope of the line of a position time graph, so I took the derivative:

$$s'(t) = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}(2t+2)}}$$

I then made $t=16$, to get:

$$s'(16) = 7.4 \cdot 10^{-3} \text{m/s}$$

Did I do this correctly? Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I'm more partial to exact answers, so I would have left the answer as $\frac{1}{136} \text{m/s}$. Besides that matter of personal preference, you definitely did everything correctly.